# ui.router o express para configurar las rutas de cada vista

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nodejs, express, ui.router

Estoy intentando desarrollar una aplicación en JavaScript full-stack. Conocía el sistema de routing que ofrece [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) basado en estados con `ui.router`, pero he visto que [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) tiene otro sistema para devolver vistas con [express](/questions/tagged/express) en función de la ruta del navegador.

¿Son cosas distintas, y totalmente compatibles? Y si se trata de lo mismo, ¿cuál de las dos es más recomendable o más eficiente?

Comment: Te recomendaría reformular la pregunta, ya que puede tener muchas respuestas posibles de acuerdo a las opiniones de cada persona, dale un rápido vistazo a la seccion de [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) así evitaras que sea cerrada.

Comment: Las respuestas a esta pregunta **no** son basadas en opiniones, cualquiera que halla trabajado en esas tecnologías lo sabe. Si tiene dudas, abstengase de votar. No toda subjetividad es inacetable aqui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ¿Son cosas distintas, y totalmente compatibles? Y si se trata de lo mismo, ¿cuál de las dos es más recomendable o más eficiente?

Son cosas diferentes. ui-router ofrece un mecanismo para enrutar cual es la vista (y controlador) activa en un momento dado para una `SPA` (Single Page Application) y **se ejecuta completamente en el cliente**.

Node.js se ejecuta del lado del servidor y no tiene ninguna forma nativa de hacer enrutamiento server side, mucho menos client side. Debes usar algún framework para el lado servidor como express.js (u otro similar) o incluso crear uno propio.

No solo son compatibles **son complementarios**, un caso de uso muy frecuente es hacer una aplicación en node.js (con express por ejemplo) que tiene un solo endpoint (o ruta server side) para obtener todos los recursos de la SPA (los html, tus javascript, tus css, librerias, etc client side) y muchos otros endpoints (otras rutas server side) formando un servicio REST API que la SPA consume via AJAX para acceder a los datos de la aplicación, usualmente comunicándose via json.

Comment: Entonces, únicamente usaría express via `app.get('/')` para cargar la SPA de primeras, y el resto configurarlo via ui.router?

Comment: Claro, usarias `app.get('/api/products')` y `app.post('/api/products')` para los puntos de entrada de los datos.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta de Emanuel Ve, es fundamental, de ahí depende como estructures esta aplicación, si con 1 sola aplicación o sub aplicación SPA, o varias aplicaciones SPA que tengan urls diferentes, ahí pasaría por definirlas en NodeJs, y ya teniendo cargada la sub aplicación SPA, te puedes manejar a nivel de AngularJS (Angular 1) con routes url en el lado cliente, y de eso último NodeJs no sería conciente

Por lo general, la apliación SPA, es 1 sola, empieza con 1 url, que manejará Node, luego ella tiene en su comportamiento SPA, algunos routes del lado cliente (definidos en angularJS es decir en el lado cliente), y talvez alguna interacción con otras url, del lado servidor, si por ejemplo tiene que irse a autenticar a donde terceros

Por lo tanto tienes que dominar del todo ambas posibilidades, y reafirmo la idea expresada por Emanuel, no podría agregar más sin redundar

Answer (score 0):

Y si vas a usar el modo html5 de angular fundamental que en el server configures que siempre devuelva el index para que refresque, ya que las rutas de angular (sea uirouter o ngrouter) van a romperse ya que son abstractas.

```
app.all("/*", function(req,res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "index.html"); // ruta al index
});
```